# HTTPS Connection is "Not Secure"

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, encryption, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a Tomcat Server on AWS with Elastic Load Balancing, with a certificate issued by Amazon. I test my app, and the url is accessible under `https`.

However, when I access it, it shows:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Question**

Why is it "Not Secure"? What does this mean? Does it mean I have not configured it correctly?  How do I configure AWS Elastic Load Balancing correctly?

**UPDATE**

My AWS instance:

[image]

```
ping 54.213.85.128
```

times out.

Security Group inbound rules:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Adding the following inbound rule, allows my to ping the ip:

[image]

However, I still cannot seem to access it via a browser, and the domain name does not access it either.

Comment: You seem determined to abuse stackoverflow by posting off-topic questions about your server configuration. The correct site to post these questions is serverfault, *not* stackoverflow.

Comment: Please read [What questions can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the actual domain name that the SSL certificate is for. If you setup an SSL  certificate for `example.com` then it isn't going to work when you go to `elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you. You are correct, I need to access it with my domain name. I have a domain name `thewhozoo.com` registered with 1&1 Domains. I previously had this pointing at my AWS IP address (`IPv4 Address 52.43.123.145`). I now see my instance IP has changed (`IPv4 Address 54.213.85.128`). So I have updated it on 1&1, but cannot seem to get it to call the server. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added rule that allows me to access `54.213.85.128` through the browser now. But when I look at the request, it is `http://54.213.85.128`. So I try `https://54.213.85.128`, but that's not available. but the following is `https://thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`. How do I access the site via `https`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a direct IP address with Elastic Beanstalk. Where are you even getting that IP address, from the EC2 instance? If you are pointing directly to the EC2 instance then you are completely bypassing the load balancer. You need to setup your domain as a CNAME record that points to `thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`. Of course since you are using a root domain that may not be possible on 1&1. You might need to switch to using Route53.

Comment: Yes, I get that IP (`IPv4 Public IP 54.213.85.128`) from the EC2 instance. You have diagnosed my problem. I will need to investigate how to set up a CNAME.  Thank you